# In Java, how do I read both Strings and Doubles from the same txt file?

Tags: java, text-files, numberformatexception

I am working on a program that implements and Adjacency Matrix in Java. I read in a txt file of City names to add the vertices, and then I have another txt file where each line is two city names and the distance in between the two cities. Here are the first 5 lines of the edge txt file.

Chicago Boston 851

Chicago Buffalo 454

Dallas Chicago 803

Dallas Cleveland 1025

Chicago Cleveland 308

I'm using the simple method of using file reader and buffered reader to read 3 lines at a time. Then I parseDouble the third line, which would be the distance (i.e. 454). I'm getting a NumberFormatException, but the strange part is I'm not getting it until it gets to the line "Dallas Chicago 803". **Why would it read the first two correctly and then stop on the third?** I will post the section of code and the exception below.

```
    //Read input from the cities_mileage.txt file, which contains the info for adding edges
    //Call addEdge in Graph class until file it empty
    FileReader file2 = new FileReader("F:/MinSpan/resources/city_mileage.txt");
    BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(file2);

    String line2 = reader2.readLine();
    String line3 = reader2.readLine();
    String line4 = reader2.readLine();
    double doubleMile = Double.parseDouble(line4);
    while (line2 != null && line3 != null && line4 != null ) //Example: line 2 = Chicago, line 3 = Boston, line4 = 851
    {
        graph.addEdge(line2, line3, doubleMile);

        line2 = reader2.readLine();
        line3 = reader2.readLine();
        line4 = reader2.readLine();
        doubleMile = Double.parseDouble(line4);
    }
```

[NumberFormatException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJxO8.png)

Comment: The exception message is telling you *exactly* what you're doing wrong. You can't parse the whole entire line as a number, just the numeric portion and only that.

Comment: The problem is a misunderstood... `reader2.readline()` is bringing to you the whole line, so `Chicago Boston 851` to `line2`, `Chicago Buffalo 454` to `line3` and `Dallas Chigaco 803` to `line4`. When you try to parse this `line4` with characters, it will throw an exception.

You should `split` your lines with spaces, like:
`String[] line = reader2.readline().split(" ");`
So line[0] will be Chigaco, line[1] Boston and line[2] 851 and then you can `double doubleMile = Double.parseDouble(line[2])`